# How do I call a function that takes several ints with a vector of ints?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly

### The problem

I'm trying to write an interpreter for a toy language, and I want it to be able to call functions located in a DLL. In some `external.dll` I have:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) void print(int val) { printf("%i\n", val); }
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

... more functions **that I don't know then names of**

}
```

Suppose I have a `std::string func;` which is the name of a proc in the DLL, possibly `"print"` or `"add"`, and a `std::vector<int> args;` whose size is the number of arguments of the target function. How would I call the correct DLL function accordingly? Ideally I would like to be able to call any function that can be loaded using `GetProcAddress`.

### My workaround

I'm currently using MSVC's inline assembler to do what I want. It's something along the lines of:

```
int WorkaroundCall(const std::string& func, const std::vector<int>& args) {
    void* proc = GetProcAddress(hmod, func.c_str()); // hmod is the DLL's HMODULE
    void* spsave, * argframe;
    size_t argsize = sizeof(int) * args.size();
    const int* argdata = args.data();

    __asm {
            mov eax, esp
            sub eax, argsize
            mov argframe, eax
    }

    memcpy(argframe, argdata, argsize);

    __asm {
            mov spsave, esp
            mov esp, argframe
            xor edx, edx
            call proc
            mov esp, spsave
    }
}
```

However, this is obviously a not a good solution because it uses Assembly and depends on the system (Something tells me this won't work on 64-bit). How can I do this better?

Comment: I've heard of this library called LibFFI, which may be relevant to what you're doing, but no matter what you use, it will probably be painful...

Comment: The description looks promising. I'll have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#define EXTERNAL_API __declspec(dllimport)
typedef void (EXTERNAL_API* LPPRINTFN)( int );
typedef int (EXTERNAL_API* LPADDFN)( int, int );

// After loading the module you get the functions.
LPPRINTFN pfnPrint = (LPPRINTFN) GetProcAddress( hmod, "print" );
LPADDFN pfnAdd = (LPADDFN) GetProcAddress( hmod, "add" );
```

Now, since you have those strings, you may want to map them to a unique value (assume the map is global):

```
typedef enum FuncType {
    Nothing = 0,
    PrintFunc = 1,
    AddFunc = 2
} EFuncType;

typedef map< string, EFuncType > TFuncNameMap;
TFuncNameMap funcNameMap;

if( pfnPrint != NULL ) funcNameMap["print"] = PrintFunc;
if( pfnAdd != NULL ) funcNameMap["add"] = AddFunc;
```

Finally, the call (excluding any bounds checking on the arguments vector):

```
int SlightlyBetterCall( const std::string& func, const std::vector<int>& args )
{
    TFuncNameMap::iterator iFuncId = funcNameMap.find(func);
    if( iFuncId == funcNameMap.end() )
        return -1; // return some error?

    int result = 0;

    switch( iFuncId->second ) {
        case PrintFunc:
            pfnPrint( args[0] );
            break;
        case AddFunc:
            result = pfnAdd( args[0], args[1] );
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

You don't really need that map...  Nothing to stop you from going:

```
if( func == "print" && pfnPrint != NULL ) {
    pfnPrint( args[0] );
}
else if( func == "add" && pfnAdd != NULL ) {
    result = pfnAdd( args[0], args[1] );
}
```

This whole thing seems a little suspicious to me, but I hope that helps you in any case =)

Comment: Hi; sorry, I should have stated in the question -- ideally, I would like the main program to have no idea what's in the DLL and let the toy client language specify what functions it wants to try to call.

Comment: Ah okay, so what's to stop the toy client language from getting the number of arguments or the argument type wrong and dying horribly? =)

Comment: Do the ends justify the means? ;-)  This is starting to look a little like COM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it:-

- You are creating space on stack,and then passing the offset to `proc`.

If stack is not the only requirement then its good to pass the address of data in the heap.

However you can allocate space on stack using arrays.

```
int WorkaroundCall(const std::string& func, const std::vector<int>& args) {
        void (*proc)(int);
        void* proc = GetProcAddress(hmod, func.c_str()); // hmod is the DLL's HMODULE
        void* spsave, * argframe;
        size_t argsize = sizeof(int) * args.size();
        const int* argdata = args.data();
        int *dat= new int[argsize];    
        memcpy(dat, argdata, argsize);
        proc(dat);
        delete[] dat;
    }
```

Comment: This won't work because you're calling the proc with only 1 argument, a pointer to where the arguments are.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in C (and hence C++), without resorting to assembly, is to declare all possible function signatures, and then call the appropriate signature based on the number of arguments.

The next thing to note is that, on 64bit builds, 'int' isn't going to cut it - the basic parameter size would be a 64bit type. As this is a windows question, I'll use types from the windows sdk to ensure that it compiles and works correctly in both Win32 and Win64.

```
#include <windows.h>
typedef INT_PTR CALLBACK Tfunc0(void);
typedef INT_PTR CALLBACK Tfunc1(INT_PTR p1);
typedef INT_PTR CALLBACK Tfunc2(INT_PTR p1,INT_PTR p2);

INT_PTR CallProc(FARPROC proc, const std::vector<INT_PTR>& args) {
    switch(args.size())
    {
    case 0: return ((TFunc0*)proc)();
    case 1: return ((TFunc1*)proc)(args[0]);
    case 2: return ((TFunc2*)proc)(args[0],args[1]);
    }
    throw some_kind_of_exception;
}
```

---

Alternatively, a templated approach could allow you to more easilly call procs:

```
template<typename RetT> 
RetT CallProc(FARPROC proc){
  return (RetT)(((TFunc0*)proc)());
}

template<typename RetT,typename Param1T> 
RetT CallProc(FARPROC proc, Param1T p1){
  return (RetT)(((TFunc1*)proc)((INT_PTR)p1));
}
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the general sense that the only solution is to use LibFFI as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066064/how-do-i-call-a-function-that-takes-several-ints-with-a-vector-of-ints#comment16116140_12066064) by Mehrdad (which, unfortunately, doesn't support MSVC), or to continue using Assembly and maintain different versions for 32 and 64 bit (which is what I'll try to do).

Generating all method signatures as suggested by Chris Becke is impractical as the toy language is to have more types than just int.

Again, sorry - I should have made it clear that the function names in the DLL aren't known to the program at compile time.

Comment: The use of INT_PTR ensures that the parameters are large enough to carry any native data type. As such, you really only need a typedef per # of parameters, and use old fashioned typecasting to coerce the parameters. Note that you will never be able to pass anything other than C compatible types anyway in a general way.

Comment: This works if arguments are always aligned to INT_PTR (which I suppose is the case here), although the code would be almost as ugly and limit the number of arguments. I'll give it a try anyways.